# Loading many images with Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I've wrote application that loads all images from special folder. When I tested it - it loaded up to 100 photos in resolution 3264*2448 in 20-30 sec. But now I've task to load up to 400 photos in resolution 5616*3744. Is it real? I think no..

Comment: Why would you want to load 400 pictures of that resolution at the same time? You can't display them at the same time.

Comment: It's certainly possible to download them all, but definitely not feasible to load them all into memory at once, nor is there a display out there that could display them all at once (hell, I'm not sure there is a display out there that could show even one in its entirety)

Comment: Ok, thanks Marjin and Josh. I also thought so, but my director make me nervous and now I absolutly sure that it's impossible to show so many pictures.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why do you need to be loading these images? Why that size and why that many? What is the project? With some context, we may be able to help you a bit more than saying it isn't feasible.